# How to deactivate onTick method in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I have Problem with `onTick()` method, I have two buttons for two different situations, in each one I will load separate dataSource, just like the `czml.html` example on Sandcastle. I have two different definition for `onTick()` method for each button seperately, to do some specific things when we reach at a specific time. In the reset method I am removing entities and dataSources of my viewer, but I cannot remove `onTick` method implementation.

When I am running my code, the default button is doing perfectly fine, but when I press other button, all those conditions that I mentioned for the first button is also happening at the same time, and it will not let my second `onTick` method to perform its job correctly. Do you know how I can deactivate the first `onTick` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [addEventListener](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Event.html#addEventListener) documentation, you'll find two different ways to undo the addition of an event listener:  One is to call the matching [removeEventListener](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Event.html#removeEventListener), and the other is to save the return value from `addEventListener` and invoke it later.

Here's some code showing both ways.  Use whichever option makes more sense for your code, but don't use both at once.

```
function onTickCallback(clock) {
    // ... do stuff with every tick ...
}

var unsubscribeTicks = viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(onTickCallback);

function unsubscribeOption1() {
    // One option is to call removeEventListener.  In this case, you
    // don't need to save "var unsubscribeTicks" at all, but you do
    // need a reference to the original onTickCallback.
    viewer.clock.onTick.removeEventListener(onTickCallback);
}

function unsubscribeOption2() {
    // The other option is to save the return value of addEventListener,
    // and later invoke it.  This could be a cleaner option if the
    // onTickCallback was declared anonymously inline.
    unsubscribeTicks();
}
```